# authorization in laravel 7 with gate

Tags: laravel, authorization

hello I want to use Authorization in my projet with gate. I define a gate in provider`\AuthServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name , function ($user) use($permission){
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }

}
```

then I define function `hasRole` in `App\User`:

```
 public function hasRole($role)
{
    if(is_string($role)) {
        return $this->roles->contains('name' , $role);
    }

    return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}
```

for example in `ProductController` I define index  such this:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('show-product');
    $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
    return view('Admin.product.all' , compact('products'));
}
```

but when I use `@can` in my blade to limit a section by Authorization,it doesn't show this section to a user with allow access to this section.